# Facing issue while sending "&" in a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I'm sending the below string.

```
"{"English":{"name":"test & test","descpt":"test"},"Telugu":{"name":"test","descpt":"test"}}"
```

request payloads are only taking the part before the "&"

Does this have any solution?

Comment: Escape it/use the entity.

Comment: I'm confused, why are you trying to put this in your header?

Comment: use as `test /& test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use encodeURIComponent().

It will escape all the characters that cannot occur verbatim in URLs:

```
var wysiwyg_clean = encodeURIComponent(stringValue);
```

In this example, the ampersand character & will be replaced by the escape sequence %26, which is valid in URLs.

Comment: you can click on this answer is useful and green check for thanks.;)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can usin  encodeURI() Method in Javascript.

It will solve the issue while sending.

```
var t=  encodeURI("{"English":{"name":"test & test","descpt":"test"},"Telugu":{"name":"test","descpt":"test"}}");
```

And Decode at the server side. depending on what technology you used.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that's probably because of double quotes,If you are sending objects with in objects make sure double check with quotes. Please enclode your whole string with single quotes. you can use:

```
'{"English":{"name":"test & test","descpt":"test"},"Telugu":{"name":"test","descpt":"test"}}'
```

If you want to send this to the request payload, then

```
encodeURIComponent('{"English":{"name":"test & test","descpt":"test"},"Telugu":{"name":"test","descpt":"test"}}')
```